# php foreach loop search mysql table with several words

Tags: php, mysql, forms, foreach, while-loop

I have a mysql table called foods with columns "id, name, addinfo, picname, mg1cup, mg100g".  I have a form where the user can submit between 1-20 food names.  The php file takes the submitted food names in an array called $terms[].  I need to search the sql table for all terms and return results for all columns for each of the terms.

However, the results are only showing the first term submitted, repeated as many times as there are inputs (for example, if two words were inputted, the first term gets outputted in the results twice - instead of first word results, then second word results).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Here's my code (I haven't added the function to sanitize the strings yet):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');

//connect to the wordpress (bluehost)DB 

require_once '../../../wp-config.php';

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die('Could not connect to mysql');

$Db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die('Could not select database.');   

//check to see if the search term has a value, matches "name" column in DB, and if so, put it into an array called terms
if (isset($_POST['terms'])) {     

    $terms = ($_POST['terms']);

        if (count($terms) > 0 ) { 

            $results=array();

            foreach($terms as $term) {

                $sql = 'SELECT * from `wpqr_foods` WHERE `name` like  "%'. $term .'%" ORDER BY name ASC';


                $Q1 = mysql_query($sql);

                if(mysql_num_rows($Q1)) {

                    while ($Res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Q1)) {

                        $results[] = $Res; 

                    }

                }

                //$results = mysql_query($sql);


                $sql = 'SELECT * from wpqr_foods WHERE name LIKE "%'. $term .'%" ORDER BY name ASC';

                $Q2 = mysql_query($sql);

                //get results

                if(mysql_num_rows($Q2)) {

                    while ($Res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Q2)) {

                        $results[] = $Res; 

                    }

                }

            }

            if (count($results) > 0 ) {

                foreach ($results as $CurRes ) {

                    echo $CurRes['name']. "<br/>"; 
                    echo $CurRes['addinfo']. "<hr/>"; 

                    /* 

                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => Apples
                    [value] => Yes
                    [addinfo] => They can eat apples.  They can also eat the skin of the apple and the leaves of the apple tree, but the tree leaves are high in calcium, so limit their intake.  They can also chew on the apple tree branches.
                    [picname] => apple
                    [mgc1cup] => 5.8
                    [mgc100g] => 4.6

                    */
                }

            }

            else {

                echo "(nothing entered)";//MEANS $TERM IS EMPTY

            }


        }
        else {

            echo "(nothing entered)";//means $_POST IS NOT SET (end of if(isset($_POST['term'])) { )

        }             
}

//function to sanitize array values from form
function sanitizeString($var) {
         if (is_array($val))
           {
           foreach ($val as $k => $v)
               {
               $val[$k] = htmlentities(strip_tags($v),ENT_QUOTES);
               }
           }
         else
           {
             $val = htmlentities(strip_tags($terms),ENT_QUOTES);
           }
        return $val;
}
?>
```

The HTML is

```
<div class="my-form">
        <form role="form" id="step1" method="post" action="/wp-content/themes/mia/vitcdata.php">
            <p class="text-box"><label for="box1">Food <span class="box-number">1&nbsp;</span></label><input type="text" name="terms[]" value="" placeholder="apples" id="box1" />&nbsp;<a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
```

The form has dynamic form fields which users can add via javascript, and they can add up to 20 text inputs, in which all inputted terms get added to the $terms[] array.

So, if I test it, use two fields, and input "apples" and "bananas", the results show all the data for "apples" repeated twice.

Comment: It looks like you're hitting the database twice and pushing result sets onto `$results` twice through each iteration.  Is that intentional?

Comment: No, that's not the intention

Comment: Try to avoid queries in a loop, for the love of efficient working.

Comment: There are 2 `SELECT` statements you might be getting the same rows for `apples` twice. Which i don't think is wrong, so that part of your script is functioning correctly i reckon. Do you have any rows for `bananas` inside your DB? Could you just go to the DB and see if there are rows present for `Bananas`?

Comment: yes there are rows for bananas.  See the test here (enter password hello) http://abyssinianguineapigtips.com/vitamin-c-calculator/  If it's a fruit or a vegetable, it's in there.

Comment: yeah, i went on that link and i saw that there are actually no rows for `bananas` exactly like i guessed. In fact it was returning me rows for `banana` ( `banana` without an `s`). Try putting `banana` in there and let us know what you see. So i think your script is functioning correctly.

Comment: Please stop using the old and unmaintained mysql_* functions to interact with the db! There are tons of articles, notices and warnings about this subject, mysqli_* and pdo on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following two ways forward:

1. It looks like the code block that queries the database and pushes results into `$results` is duplicated.  You probably want to get rid of the duped block as that will create 2x results for each distinct term.
2. I suspect what's actually getting passed to the server through the form is a string containing whitespace-separated (or commas, or whichever separator the user chose to enter) terms.  Even though you've chosen to pass it (and receive it server-side) as an array, it is actually a string and you will have to `explode` it (or some other method) yourself into an array.  To check if that's the case (and if you haven't do so already), somewhere inside the `foreach ($terms as $term)` loop you should inspect `$term` to see if it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are correct.  When I echo $term I only get the first result.

Comment: Thank you.  When I remove the second $sql= SELECT * from....$Q2=mysql_query($sql).... section, it works as it should.  Wow.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, you can check a related question here:
[Using OR in LIKE Query in MySQL to compare multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106888/using-or-in-like-query-in-mysql-to-compare-multiple-fields)

You might have to do something like this in your query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from wpqr_foods WHERE name LIKE "%'. $term .'%" OR addinfo LIKE "%'. $term .'%" ORDER BY name ASC';
```

OR,

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `wpqr_foods` WHERE CONCAT(name, addinfo ) LIKE "%'. $term .'%" ORDER BY name ASC';
```