# MySQL search using multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table who have a city and description columns and my web page have a single input for search string ..

if i type into my input `furniture production` i get `company name`, so its fine, but if i want do something like this `furniture production london` string with city, i do not get any result.

How can i fix this query to work with city column or other column?

```
SELECT slug, title FROM catalog WHERE city || description LIKE '%$keyword%
```

Comment: Look up Fulltext Search.

Comment: what all search terms are acceptable? what about `london furniture production`, `furniture london`. Any query satisfying these multiple search filter would have poor performance.

Comment: I think user can type in both way, so it will be good if query can work in both way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using OR in LIKE Query in MySQL to compare multiple fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106888/using-or-in-like-query-in-mysql-to-compare-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, performing a search with such "fluid" criteria will be really expensive on the DB.

Anyway, if this is the path you want to take, here's my attempt:

```
SELECT slug, title FROM catalog 
WHERE CONCAT(city, description) LIKE '$keyword'
OR CONCAT(description, city) LIKE '$keyword'
```

To make this work, you may wanna replace all spaces with `%` and maybe put leading and trailing `%` in the code.

I reckon the code which performs the query is PHP, so this could do it:

```
$keyword = "%" . str_replace(" ", "%", $keyword) . "%";
```

Like I said, this will be **very very** heavy on the DB, specially if the number of rows is important. Try to optimize the columns for full-text search and maybe make sure the search criteria can't be too short in the input form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! It was exactly what i need. Thanks! I think it will be not so much rows in the db, about ~3k, but i will think about full-text search.